No logro importar el javascript de FOSJsRoutingBundle mediante AssetMapper
Estoy inicinado con el uso del componente AssetMapper de Symfony y en el caso del bundle FOSJsRoutingBundle no he logrado importar su clase javascript mediante el archivo importmap.php del componente. La solución momentánea ha sido mantener incluidos en el base layout los dos script del bundle como tradicionalmente se ha hecho.
El fichero importmap.php me ha quedado como sigue (resumiendo):
return [
    'auth' => [
        'path' => './assets/auth.js',
        'entrypoint' => true,
    ],
    'app' => [
        'path' => './assets/app.js',
        'entrypoint' => true,
    ],      
    'cargos' => [
        'path' => './assets/cargos.js',
        'entrypoint' => true,
    ],
    'setup' => [
        'path' => './assets/setup.js',
        'entrypoint' => true,
    ],
    'usuarios' => [
        'path' => './assets/usuarios.js',
        'entrypoint' => true,
    ],      
    'jquery' => [
        'path' => './assets/libs/jquery/jquery3.7.0.min.js',
    ],  
    'jquery_global' => [
        'path' => './assets/common/jquery_global.js',
    ],
    'fos-routing' => [
        'path' => 'bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js',
    ],
    'RoutingData' => [
        'path' => './assets/fos_js_routes.js',
    ],
];

En el entrypoint app.js por ejemplo, importo de la siguiente forma:
import 'jquery_global';  
// otras sentencias import
import {Routing} from 'fos-routing';
import RoutingData from 'RoutingData';

Routing.setData(RoutingData);

De esa manera, me salta el error: SyntaxError: The requested module 'fos-routing' does not provide an export named 'default' que entiendo implica que desde el modulo que se importa no existe una clase o funcion a exportar por defecto.
Cuál sería la manera correcta de importar dicho javascript??

Hola. Al usar AssetMapper hay varias cosas que cambian. Por ejemplo, en los archivos tales como app.js y otros, tienes que poner la extensión y en algunos casos puede que también la ruta, de los archivos que quieres importar. Por favor revisa la Guía de Actualización a AssetMapper. Considera también hacer depuraciones con php bin/console debug:asset-map y otros, tal y como explica la doc para ver que todo está correcto.

@A.Cedano la cuestion es que el navegador hace el preload correctamente de los dos ficheros del FOS, y sí en el importmap.php se incluyen las extensiones de los archivos javascript como muestro en la pregunta. El tema es que no entiendo cómo se cargaría entonces la clase Routing desde el asset importado.

Precisamente, cuando hablo de poner la extensión no me refiero al archivo importmap.php sino al asset. Por ejemplo, en app.js, en los import tú debes poner la extensión de los archivos. Esa es una de las novedades de AssetMapper, de acuerdo a la guía (primer enlace de mi comentario anterior). Observa los ejemplos en el apartado Changes in Asset Files. Lo correcto es lo que está en verde. Traducido dice: ...

Los archivos dentro del directorio assets/ no requieren muchos cambios, pero es posible que deba realizar algunos ajustes. Ahora, cada vez que importe archivos, debe incluir la extensión del archivo.

"Me voy a responder yo mismo". La solución estuvo en descargar mediante el comando de consola importmap:require el archivo javascript que ya viene con el bundle FOSJsRoutingBundle, pero en este caso desde un CDN (https://www.jsdelivr.com/). Con esto hago notar lo siguiente: el comando importmap:require se encarga de obtener la versión del archivo javascript compatible con módulos es6 y por tanto el mismo incluye las sentencias export y/o export default necesaria para hacer la importación desde nuestros propios módulos.
Algunas consideraciones sobre FOSJsRoutingBundle a tener en cuenta:
El bundle además del archivo javascript routes.js, hace uso de un archivo en formato json o js que contendrá todas las reglas de ruteo expuestas al javascript, y cuando hacemos un import desde nuestros módulos, también debemos importar dichas reglas desde el fichero que las contiene:

bin/console: fos:js:dump --format=js --target=./fos_js_routes.js --callback="export default"
Note que la expresión callback garantiza el fichero generado haga un export por defecto del objeto que contiene las reglas de ruteo expuesta.
Agregar una entrada del fichero anterior al importmap.php, quedando de forma resumida:

return [
'auth' => [
'path' => './assets/auth.js',
'entrypoint' => true,
],
'app' => [
'path' => './assets/app.js',
'entrypoint' => true,
],
'jquery' => [
'version' => '3.7.1',
],
'fos-routing' => [
'version' => '0.0.6',
],
'RoutingData' => [
'path' => './assets/fos_js_routes.js',
],
];
Por último en nuestro fichero app.js hacer los import correspondientes por ejemplo hacer:
import Routing from 'fos-routing';
import RoutingData from 'RoutingData';
Routing.setData(RoutingData);

El OP A.Cedano me hace referencia en un comentario a la documentación de AssetMapper y recalcaba algo, es necesario incluir la extensiones de los archivos javascript en nuestro módulos cada vez que los vayamos a importar y así lo refleja la doc. Pues la verdad que de la única manera que me ha funcionado el import, es haciendo referencia solamente al nombre de las entradas en importmap.php. No se si es que yo uso la versión 7.1 de sf en esta aplicación y algo ha cambiado al respecto
